java.lang.RuntimeException Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.LOCAL_BROADCAST_PURCHASES_UPDATED (has extras) }
Fatal Exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.LOCAL_BROADCAST_PURCHASES_UPDATED flg=0x10 pkg=insighthealthapps.geniusbiofeedback (has extras) } in com.android.billingclient.api.zzn@7185613
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1568)
       at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)

after one time of payment success  it will fail with this error second time. Also cause when product is already owned by user.
And I do not have any receiver in my code
